# CXF WebService client intermittent occurrence of java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: cxf, websphere-7

We have a few CXF Web Services deployed on Websphere Application Server 7.0.0. Its a multi-server environment with load balancer.

We have a multi-threaded web service client (acts as a cache tool) which calls web services and service requests from caller. So essentially, request flow is like this -

caller -> CXF WebService client (multhithreaded) -> F5 load balancer -> Websphere ASs

This all works fine, but some times we see "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out" on our WebService client. On one of the Websphere AS (which is handling this incoming request), we see "java.io.IOException: SRVE0080E: Invalid content length". We are not able to reproduce this issue in our test environment and randomly occurs in client's production environment. The occurrence is not very frequent and we verified that load is also not that much. Request doesn't contain too much of data, it just has an "id" of the object which client requested from server. Since server never received the full request data, so the webservice method never gets called.

Full stack trace at client's side -

```
[pool-1-thread-643] WARN  phase.PhaseInterceptorChain Interceptor has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:472)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:254)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:123)
    at $Proxy55.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.***.****.***service.***Thread.retrieve(***Thread.java:344)
    at com.***.****.***service.***Thread.handleMessage(***Thread.java:232)
    at com.***.****.***service.***Thread.run(***Thread.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2046)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:2022)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1947)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 13 more
```

Full stack trace Server side -

```
java.io.IOException: SRVE0080E: Invalid content length
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.http.HttpInputStream.finish(HttpInputStream.java:184)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.http.HttpInputStream.close(HttpInputStream.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.finish(SRTServletRequest.java:2617)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTConnectionContext.finishConnection(SRTConnectionContext.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1048)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
```

Does anyone have any guess what might be happening? Is there a possibility that the thread which is making webservice call is put on wait or suspension state by JVM before it could complete the request and later on socket timed out because JVM didnt reschedule this thread again within 1 min (we have set socket timeout to 1 min)? Is it possible load balancer not able to forward the entire request data to server?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can consider catching the SocketTimeOut exception at the client side, since it is a timeout, there doesn't seem to be a way to avoid it. But catching it and giving an appropriate message instead of throwing the full stack trace might be more acceptable from a customer point of view. No idea about the other Invalid content length error you are getting, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, that we are doing anyways. Full stacktrace is just logged in log file.